# (Blender Newbie) How would I Smooth This Rigid Mesh?

Tags: mesh

I have a mesh that I made in a game and imported to blender. Its only one mesh already unioned but problem is that i dont know how to smooth out the rigid lines as im quite new to blender(Started Today lol). If anyone knows how to please let me know. Thanks
[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that even though they belong to the same mesh, they don't form a continuous surface, and are not part of the same "mesh chunk". You would need to remodel those parts, or at least the intersecting regions so the form a continuous surface.

Comment: You could try sculpting / smooth .. see this video for a demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDoPIpZsVKA&list=PLboXykqtm8dydLQFk962346_TrAgzfMCF&index=4